# Remote Debug for Cloud Foundry application fails when connecting eclipse remote debugger to forwarded local port

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ssh, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to remotely debug a Spring boot application deployed on a cloud foundry Instance. Below are the steps that I'm following to setup remote debug using eclipse:

1. Setting up `JBP_CONFIG_DEBUG: '{enabled: true}'` environment variable for the application.
2. After that I'm setting up the local port forwarding to my app container with `cf ssh -N -T -L 8000:localhost:8000 <APP_NAME>`
3. Then I'm setting up the remote debug configuration in eclipse as shown below image:[Eclipse remote debug setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5dYz.png)

After that when I try to start remote debug session, It tried to connect to the app but fails with the message at the port forwarded terminal:

> connect to localhost:8000 failed: ssh: rejected: connect failed (dial
>   tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: getsockopt: connection refused)

Please help, if anyone has any clue about this error!!

Comment: Did you fix this issue? It seems we have the same problem since some days.

Comment: @funfriedNope, we tried many variants to solve it, but couldn't able to.

Comment: in the meantime I found out what our problem is, in our case it‘s a bug in the buildpack we use and we got a workaround from the buildpack maintainer. Maybe you also want to try it so I added it as an answer (due to formatting)

Comment: @funfried is it due to the fact that the custom CF space has restricted ports?

Comment: not sure tbh, I only know it works for us and the buildpack we use. The maintainers of our buildpack (which is closed source) said they will fix it in the future, so I guess it could be anything :/

Answer (score 2):

You might have to restage the application for the change to take place, debug configuration to change.

You can use alternatively ssh into the container using `cf ssh <application name>` and check that the debug port is opened on not using `netstat -an`

Answer (score 0):

We had some issues as well, but with a specific java buildback, but anyway mabe it'll help you in your case as well, try:

`cf set-env <app-name> JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_OPTS '[java_opts: "-XX:+ForceDebuggingOnDemand"]'`

`cf restage <app-name>`

Answer (score 0):

try to change debugging port like this:

```
JBP_CONFIG_DEBUG "{enabled: true, port: 8001}"
```